# Unable to invoke API gateway from Lambda {'message':'Forbidden'}

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, lambda, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

We have exposed a Lambda A through public API on the API gateway regional endpoint. We have also created the API key. We are able to call this API from the local desktop since this is a public API. But we are not able to call this API via Lambda B. Now both Lambda A and B are inside VPC with internet access. Below is the code we are using

```
import requests
import psycopg2
import time
from datetime import datetime
import uuid
import json
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    url = 'https://xxx.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/v1'
    myinp = {
    "s3url": "s3://xxxx-aws-dev-xxx/xxx/xxx.jpg",
    "sourcename":"xxx"
    }
    Api_key  = "xxxCJnl97g5hfke85jmkG1a2F9uS4ZplaJxLjxxx"
    header = {"X-Api-Key" : Api_key}
    x = requests.post(url, json = myinp, headers=header).json()
    print(x)
```

We are getting below response when Lambda invokes the API.

```
{'message':'forbidden'}
```

We have also tried different key headers like `x-api-key` and `api-key` but no fate.
Please let us know in case more info is required.

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to invoke API gateway from Lambda

Since your error message is `{'message':'forbidden'}`, it seems like you do invoke the API Gateway. If you were unable to invoke, you wouldn't see this message.

Most probably some permissions settings or the URL is incorrect.

Comment: Hi, @Brian thanks for the info. But as mentioned we are able to invoke the API from the local instance and the response is as expected. Only the call from lambda B is facing an issue even though the credentials are the same.